Using Hardy-Littlewood inequality to prove a theorem about interleaving sequences
Fix a positive integer $k$. For each $i\in[k]$ let $g_i=(g_it)_{t=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of numbers. Given an infinite sequence $(a_t)_{t=1}^\infty$ taking values in $[k]$ define the interleaving sequence $I(g,a)$ as follows:
$$
I(g,a)_t=g_{a_t,1+n_{a_t}(a,t-1)}
$$
where
$$
n_i(a,t-1)=\sum_{s=1}^{t-1}\mathbb{I}(a_s=i)
$$
Now Lattimore and ... claim that if $g_i$ is decreasing for all $i\in[k]$ the greedy choice defined by $a*_t=\text{argmax}_ig_{i,1+n_i(a*,t-1)}$ has the largest discounted sum, i.e.
$$
\sum_{t=1}^\infty\alpha^{t-1}I(g,a*)
$$
is the supremum of $\sum_{t=1}^\infty\alpha^{t-1}I(g,a)$ for every possible $a\in[k]^\mathbb{N}$. They say that this can be proved using the Hardy-Littlewood equality which for increasing sequences $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ of real numbers and any permutation $\sigma$ of the natural numbers says
$$
\sum x_in_i\geq \sum x_in_{\sigma(i)}
$$
Now I understand that if $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are decreasing, then $(-x_n)$ and $(-y_n)$ are increasing and we could henceforth get a similar inequality. Also I can see how I can prove that any permutation of $I(g,a*)$ will result in a smaller discounted sum. But not all choice sequences $a\in[k]^\mathbb{N}$ result in permutations of $I(g,a*)$. (For example $a^*$ may be a constant sequence.) I don't know how to surmount this difficulty.
